# Can generics be used to combine these methods?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to setup a comparison based on input from a file (ie two values are in an XML options file and read in and I want to compare them).

I can do this, but it is seeming a bit verbose.  I thought I would post it here and see if there is a way that I can get my comparison done via Generics.

Here are my methods:

```
// Only equal is supported for strings.
public static bool CompareString(this ComparisionOperator oper, string leftSide, string rightSide)
{
    return leftSide == rightSide;
}


public static bool CompareDouble(this ComparisionOperator oper, double leftSide, double rightSide)
{
    switch (oper)
    {
        case ComparisionOperator.LessThan:
            return leftSide < rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.GreaterThan:
            return leftSide > rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo:
            return leftSide <= rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            return leftSide >= rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.EqualTo:
            return leftSide == rightSide;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("oper");
    }
}


public static bool CompareDateTime(this ComparisionOperator oper, DateTime leftSide, DateTime rightSide)
{
    switch (oper)
    {
        case ComparisionOperator.LessThan:
            return leftSide < rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.GreaterThan:
            return leftSide > rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo:
            return leftSide <= rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            return leftSide >= rightSide;
        case ComparisionOperator.EqualTo:
            return leftSide == rightSide;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("oper");
    }
}

//  Repeated for Int (and maybe GUID)
```

Am I better off just repeating these?

The catch I am having is comparing Strings is not the same as comparing numbers or date times.  If I just create a generic method and pass in a string, will it get confused when if it tries to do a less than on a string?

Comment: Look around Comparer<T>.Default ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refactor this using generics for some types by restricting to types that implement [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx).

```
public static bool Compare<T>(this ComparisionOperator oper, T leftSide, T rightSide)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    switch (oper)
    {
        case ComparisionOperator.LessThan:
            return leftSide.CompareTo(rightSide) < 0;
        case ComparisionOperator.GreaterThan:
            return leftSide.CompareTo(rightSide) > 0;
        case ComparisionOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo:
            return leftSide.CompareTo(rightSide) <= 0;
        case ComparisionOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            return leftSide.CompareTo(rightSide) >= 0;
        case ComparisionOperator.EqualTo:
            return leftSide.CompareTo(rightSide) == 0;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("oper");
    }
}
```

This will work for quite a few types, as `Int32`, `Double`, `Single`, etc all implement `IComparable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

> will it get confused when if it tries to do a less than on a string?

Your program will just crash as those operators are not defined for the String class.  You could accept an IComparer that will do the comparison for you, and that comparer can define what it means for one string to be "less than" of "greater than" another.